# How to display the content from .txt file into a div using jQuery load?

Tags: jquery, html

I am not sure where I am going wrong here.
I have a `div` and a `button`.

On the click of the `button`, I am trying to display the contents from a `.txt` file in this `div`.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='abc'>AA</div>
    <button id='bt'>Submit</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$('#bt').click(function() {
    $('#abc').load('hello.txt');
})
```

`'hello.txt'` file is located in the same folder where `.html` file is located.

Nothing is displayed and I don't get any error either.

Comment: Are you on a local server or file system? Which browser?

Comment: file is in my local system. I tried this in IE8,IE12 and Chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you working locally? It will work, but when testing, you won't get results from a localdrive, you'll need an actual http server. The invisible error is an XMLHttpRequest error.

Comment: When you're writing Javascript, it's always handy to keep the JS console (for whatever browser) open, so you can catch errors that normally are not shown.

Comment: oh..okay..yes file is in my local system. So how can I test it if I don't have a server setup right now?

Comment: @PEJK [take a look here](http://www.tnghardware.com/delete/foo2.html). It works just fine :)

Comment: If you have python installed on your computer, you can start a very simple web server locally with only the command (from the directory where the files are located): `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` - then visit http://localhost:8000/index.html - more info here: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Comment: Or if not, you can download [Brackets](http://brackets.io/), which is a great **free** IDE. When you click their Live Preview button (lightening bolt in upper right), it sets up a localhost etc and you will see it work--only with chrome though. Fantastic little editor with live HTML/CSS updates (no need to refresh browser).